# Open link in console application on default browser

Tags: c#

Hello I'm trying to make app that will open every time when I start pc. And the app will open some links in my browser (firefox). I tried Process.Start("http://www.google.com"); but it says "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified." Do someone know what code should I use to open link in Console application on a default browser?

Comment: You should document the OS version you use.  Put the [STAThread] attribute on your Main() method and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
string request = "https://www.google.com";
ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = request,
    UseShellExecute = true
};
Process.Start(ps);
```

You will need to add

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to Add `start` at start of you statement.

```
start https://www.google.com
```